# MongoDB Dynamic DB Selection / Creation

Tags: php, mongodb

In Mongo DB you can do the following :

```
$m = new Mongo();
// select a database
$db=$m->databaseName;    // this creates/returns the db "databaseName"
```

How can I make a function such that dataBasename is passed as a dynamic variable? The below function currently fails.

```
load_db("databaseName");    

function load_db($dbname)
{
$m = new Mongo();
$db=$m->$dbname;   // I have also tried {$dbname}, with no success.

return $db;
}
```

Answer (score 5):

You can use `$db = $m->selectDb( $variable );`: http://php.net/manual/en/mongo.selectdb.php